# Parallel.For skipping elements

Tags: c#, multithreading

In the following code, it seems that only every other element of the array is getting populated. Why?

```
Random rand = new Random();
int byteLength = 10000000;
var result = new byte[10][];
Parallel.For(0, 10, (i) =>
{
    int length = rand.Next(byteLength);
    var tempResult = new byte[length];
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    rand.NextBytes(tempResult);
    result[i] = tempResult;
});
```

Contrast with this (non-parallel) code, which does fill every element:

```
rand = new Random();
var result2 = new byte[10][];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int length = rand.Next(byteLength);
    var tempResult = new byte[length];
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    rand.NextBytes(tempResult);
    result2[i] = tempResult;
}
```

Comparing to [the examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783584.aspx) in the docs at MSDN, I suspect this is because `result` is outside the `Parallel.For` delegate - thus, the threads are having trouble when accessing `result`. But as a newbie to multithreading, I'm not sure this is the case.

Comment: You're using a single instance of `Random` from multiple threads. That's a bad idea - `System.Random` isn't thread-safe. It should still be populating every element though... what exactly are you seeing? Null references, or just entries where all bytes are 0?

Comment: System.Random is not thread safe.

Comment: Thank you for heads up on System.Random. Changing so instances are created within the delegate seems to fix the problem. Anyone care to write as answer, and I will mark as as answered?

Comment: Although Random is not threadsafe (as commented to your question by other posters) there remains the question as to why you are seeing unpopulated data, since the iteration variable `i` is not dependent on the value of Randoms return. In this case I believe that Random is returning zero when called in an unthreadsafe manner, leading to you concluding the data was not filled, but you just had an empty array. This can be tested by assigning a non-empty array initially and seeing if your routine changes it to a zero length. I think this is the full answer as to "Why ?"

Comment: This might be useful for you. https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/

Comment: @PhillipH good point. Looking at the first scenario again, I am getting a result of a zero-length byte array for the elements that weren't getting populated. And, per the test you suggested, the non-empty array is getting changed to zero length. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Well, even if we use `ConcurrencyBag` for `result` it's still the same. The problem is that sometimes `rand.NextBytes(tempResult);` returns empty array. As mentioned before `System.Random` is not thread-safe and this might somehow result in incorrect execution of this method. Note that if we change delay to `Thread.Sleep(5000);` all works as expected.

Comment: @AaronThomas I'll bang it in as the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Random is not threadsafe (as commented to your question by other posters) there remains the question as to why you are seeing unpopulated data, since the iteration variable i is not dependent on the value of Randoms return. In this case I believe that Random is returning zero when called in an unthreadsafe manner, leading to you concluding the data was not filled, but you just had an empty array. This can be tested by assigning a non-empty array initially and seeing if your routine changes it to a zero length. I think this is the full answer as to "Why ?"